# cant retrive value from db in code CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to retrive id from a table an post it to another table but i cant fetch the value.
This is my model post model code

```
  $this->db->insert('contents', $data);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('class_sections');
            $this->db->where('id','=', '29');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $user_id = $query->id;
            
            if (isset($content_role) && !empty($content_role)) {
                $total_rec = count($content_role);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $total_rec; $i++) {
                    $content_role[$i]['content_id'] = $insert_id;
                    $content_role[$i]['user_id'] = $user_id;
                }
                $this->db->insert_batch('content_for', $content_role);
            }
            $message      = INSERT_RECORD_CONSTANT." On contents id ".$insert_id;
            $action       = "Insert";
            $record_id    = $insert_id;
            $this->log($message, $record_id, $action);
```

this is my controller code

```
 $content_for = array();
            foreach ($content_available as $cont_avail_key => $cont_avail_value) {
                $content_for[] = array('role' => $cont_avail_value);
            }


            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('content_title'),
                'type' => $this->input->post('content_type'),
                'note' => $this->input->post('note'),
                'class_id' => $classes,
                'cls_sec_id' => $section_id,
                'created_by'=> $this->customlib->getStaffID(),
                //'date' => date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($this->input->post('upload_date'))),
                'file' => $this->input->post('file'),
                'is_public' => $visibility
            );

            if(isset($_POST['upload_date']) && $_POST['upload_date']!=''){

                $data['date']=date('Y-m-d', $this->customlib->datetostrtotime($this->input->post('upload_date')));
            }
            
            $insert_id = $this->content_model->add($data, $content_for);
```

i am trying to post the user_id to the content for table. but i am not able to run the database query. i am new to this frame work and dont know much abut it
please help me...

Comment: what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: i want to get the id of the table

Comment: you want to get the ID of the user or the table? what you are asking isn't clear